# What do we know about isospectral Cayley graphs?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, graph-theory, lie-groups, isospectrality

Let $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_1(G_1,S_1)$ (respectively $\Gamma_2=\Gamma_2(G_2,S_2)$) be a Cayley graph for the group $G_1$ and the finite generating set $S_1$ (respectively $G_2$ and the finite generating set $S_2$).

- If we assume $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ are isospectral, what restrictions does this place on the underlying groups $G_1$ and $G_2$?
- Conversely, given two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ is there a choice of $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are isospectral? If the answer is in general no, are there known conditions on $G_1$ and $G_2$ (other than $G_1=G_2$) that guarantee an affirmative answer?

(As noted in the comments below, the converse has an obvious answer if the groups are finite, so for these questions we can assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are infinite, while keeping the restriction that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite).

Finally,

- What can be said about the expansion properties of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ if they are isospectral?

Comment: I apologise in advance for this trivial comment: the complete graph is a Cayley graph for every group of the appropriate cardinality. Hence, even knowning that two groups have isomorphic Cayley graphs doesn't tell you much about the groups. You'll probably need to make your question more precise.

Comment: @verret Indeed, the Cayley graph of a finite group is completely uninteresting - the OP can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it is implicit that the groups in question are infinite.  Indeed, there are quite a few results about the spectral theory of Cayley graphs of infinite discrete groups.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I have added some details about the question. Can you kindly explain why the Cayley graph of a finite group is uninteresting? And what is known about spectral theory of infinite discrete groups?

Comment: @verret I guess you are referring to the fact that non-isomorphic groups can have isomorphic Cayley graphs - right? Any examples?

Comment: @verret Is there some invariant across the different Cayley graphs that are possible for a group?

Comment: @user6818 I already gave an example. The complete graph is a Cayley graph for any group of the appropriate cardinality (finite or not). Thus, in some extreme cases, it is impossible to recover any information about a group from a Cayley graph except its order. If you want more, then you need to tell us something about what you are assuming about the Cayley graphs.

Comment: It is probably assumed by the OP that the Cayley graphs are only with respect to *finite* generating subsets, since otherwise there's no Laplacian and isospectral is meaningless. This allows complete graphs only for finite groups, and to have isomorphic Cayley graphs (wrt finite generating subsets) is a strong condition for finitely generated groups in general.

Comment: @verret Let's be clear: the "Cayley graph of a group" is not well defined: you must consider the Cayley graph of a group together with a (finite) generating set.  As your comment pointed out, you can always choose the generating set of a finite group to be the whole group in which case you get the complete graph, and hence there are no nontrivial invariants of "the Cayley graph" of a finite group.  You can correct me if I'm missing something, but I don't see how this is inconsistent with what you said (let alone inflammatory!)

Comment: There are invariants of Cayley graphs of infinite groups coming from the fact that any two generating sets yield quasi-isometric graphs, and some of these invariants can be picked up by spectral theory.  But the spectrum does depend to some extent on the generating set, and I'm interpreting the question to mean "how much is the spectrum constrained by the underlying group?"

Comment: Note that the meaning of "isospectral" is still to clarify. Once $(G,S)$ is given with $S$ finite generating subset, we have a Laplace operator on $\ell^2(G)$. For $(G_1,S_1)$, $(G_1,S_2)$, we get two Laplace operator. What is meant by isospectral? (in the standard Cayley graph of $\mathbf{Z}$, there are no eigenvalues). Is it required that the Laplace operators are intertwined by an isomorphism (isometry?) between the Hilbert spaces $\ell^2(G_1)$ and $\ell^2(G_2)$?

Comment: There are many examples of nontrivial isospectral (even isomorphic) *finite* graphs which can be described as Cayley graphs using a variety of different (finite) groups. For example, if $G$ is the elementary abelian group of order 16 with generators w,x,y,z and if $S=\{1,w,x,y,z,wxyz\}$ then $\Gamma(G,S)$ is a graph on which twelve different groups act sharply transitively and therefore we can describe this graph as a Cayley graph using any of these 12 groups. Given the fact that the first question is wide open on *finite* groups, I doubt if there is much we could say in the infinite case?

Comment: @KenW.Smith Can you kindly specify what is this "elementary Abelian group of order 16"?  - And what are these these 12 graphs are are isospectral?

Comment: @KenW.Smith Given two Caley graphs is there some simple way to see if they are isospectral?

Comment: @YCor What do you mean by "converse has an obvious answer" ? (in your edit to the question)

Comment: @user6818 The elementary abelian group of order 16 is the unique abelian group with *smallest* exponent, that is, every element has order 2.  It is isomorphic to the additive group of the vector space of dimension 4 over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the set of binary quadruples. In that viewpoint, $S=\{0000,1000,0100,0010,0001,1111\}.$

Comment: @user6818 Given two Cayley graphs there is no clear way to tell if they are isospectral.  The spectrum of a finite Cayley graph is equivalent to the set of (eigenvalues of the) images of the set $S$ under the various irreducible representations of the group, but I am merely rephrasing the question in terms of group representations.

Comment: @user6818 A correction on my graph in groups of order 16 -- to avoid loops, remove the identity element from the set $S$. This gives a $(16,5,0,2)$ strongly regular graph.  As for the 12 graphs that occur -- they are all the same; they $are$ isomorphic! -- and so my point simply if that there are LOTS of different groups giving the *same* graph so if you expand the question to isopectral graphs, the set of groups will grow even more.  There are many, many different Cayley graphs that give the same graph *and* there are many nonisomorphic graphs that are isospectral.

Comment: @user6818 As I said, I didn't write this edit, which was Neil Hoffman's pending edit, and didn't expect the edit to be written on my name. All I can say in this direction is what's obvious: from the Laplacian you can recognize that the group is finite, and recognize its cardinal. [For 2 finite groups of the same cardinal, the condition "to admit isospectral Cayley graphs" is empty, but I expect the information that the Laplacian of a certain finite Cayley graph has a given form can sometimes provide a nontrivial information]

Comment: @user6818 still, for infinite Cayley graphs you haven't defined "isospectral".

Comment: I suggest you tell us what sorts of examples you have in mind.  Right now, the question is a bit too vague.